# Not able insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to follow a tutorial and seem not to be able to add the data into the database and have did check the code and do not seem to find why it is not working. The code should insert the data into the database but instead the page refreshes when the button is clicked. kindly please point out where i gone wrong. as i am also new to php. below would be my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<?php

include ("includes/db.php");

 ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>inserting Product</title>

    <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="skyblue">


<form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table align="center" width="700" border="2" bgcolor="orange">

<tr align="center">
    <td colspan="7"><h2>Insert New Post Here</h2></td>
  </tr>


<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>Product Title:</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="60" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>Product Category:</b></td>
  <td>
<select name="product_cat" >
   <option>Select a Category</option>
<?php
$get_cats ="select * from categories";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

While ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){


//$cat_id = $row_cats['cats_id'];
$cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";


}


?>

</select>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>Product Brand:</b></td>
  <td>
    <select name="product_brand" >
      <option>Select a Brand</option>
<?php
$get_brands = "select * from brands";

$run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

While ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){


//$cat_id = $row_cats['cats_id'];
$brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

echo "<option value='brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";

}



 ?>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>Product Image:</b></td>
  <td><input type="file" name="product_image" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>Product Price:</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="product_price" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>Product Description:</b></td>
  <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords:</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50" required /></td>
</tr>



<tr align="center">
  <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="inset_post" value="Insert Product Now" /></td>
</tr>


</table>

</form>

  </body>
  </html>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

//input data from the fields
$product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
$product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
$product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
$product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
$product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

//input image from feild
$product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
$product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

//move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");


 echo $insert_product = "insert into products(product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords)values('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";

//$insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

//if($insert_pro){

//echo"<script>alert('Product has been inserted!')</script>";
//echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self'</script>)";

//}


}

 ?>

    enter code here
```

Comment: (1) do you realize the code running your `insert into` query is commented out?    (2) it's usually best to try to reduce your code sample to a minimum reproducible example before posting it here.

Comment: Look at the submit input element, `...name="inset_post"...`, it should be `name="insert_post"`

Answer (score 1):

Your submit button has name "inset_post" instead of "insert"

Comment: Thanks allot i totally missed that it is working now.